# jQuery - query doesn't stop after return false is used

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm having a problem... when a user clicks submit - the error message shows, but the jQuery doesn't seem to stop on Return False;

See code below:

```
    function validateSubmit(){
   // this will loop through each row in table
   // Make sure to include jquery.js
   $('tr').each( function() {
      // Find first input
      var input1 = $(this).find('input').eq(0);
      var qty1 = input1.val();
      // Find Second input
      var input2 = $(this).find('input').eq(1);
      var qty2 = input2.val();
      // Find third input
      var input3 = $(this).find('input').eq(2);
      var qty3 = input3.val();
      // Find select box
      var selectBx = $(this).find('select');
      var selectVal = selectBx.val();
        if(qty1 === '' && selectVal != 'Please Select...') {
            alert("You've chosen an option, but not entered a quantity to dispute, please check your inputs.");
            return false;           
        }
        if(qty1 != '' && selectVal === 'Please Select...') {
            alert("You've entered a quantity, but not chosen why, please check your reasons.");
            return false;           
        }
        if (qty1 > qty2) {
            alert("For one of your entries, the disputed quantity is larger than the shipped quantity.");
            return false;           
        }
   });   
}
```

HTML where it's called

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>Item ID</th><th>Description</th><th>Dispute Quantity</th><th>Shipped Quantity</th><th>Ordered Quantity</th><th>Reason</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `artran09` WHERE `invno` = '$invoiceno'") or die(mysql_error());
                        echo "<center>";
                        $i = -1;        
                        echo "<form action=\"submitdispute.php?invno=".$invoiceno."&ordate=".$placed."\" method=\"POST\" onsubmit=\"return validateSubmit();\">";

                            while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {              
                                $i += 1;                                    
                                echo "<tr>"; 
                                echo "<td>".$info['item']."</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>".$info['descrip']."</td>";       

                                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" input name=".$i." onKeyPress=\"return numbersonly(this, event)\"  maxLength=\"3\"></td>"; 

                                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=".$info['qtyshp']." name = \"ship$i\" onKeyPress=\"return numbersonly(this, event)\" maxLength=\"3\" disabled=\"disabled\"></td>"; 

                                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=".$info['qtyord']." onKeyPress=\"return numbersonly(this, event)\" maxLength=\"3\" disabled=\"disabled\"></td>"; 

                                echo "<td><select name = \"reason$i\">";
                                echo "<option>Please Select...</option>";
                                echo "<option>Short/Not received</option>";
                                echo "<option>Damaged Goods</option>";
                                echo "<option>Product Not Ordered</option>";                    
                                echo "</select></td>";

                                echo "</tr>"; 
                            }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "Dispute" name ="Submit">
    </form>
```

Any ideas??  Help massively appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the HTML output on the client-side? Also, is there any JS error by any chance?

Comment: The HTML output is a simple pass-through PHP, it really just sends you to 

header("location:index.php");

It'd be pointless showing you that, unfortunately my strengths are in PHP, not so much in jQuery

When i take out the preventDefault call, it runs through - shows the error message so it is finding the line at fault, but then it doesn't hit the return false, it just keeps submitting

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and remove every bit of inline JavaScript from the HTML/PHP.  Then leverage the power of jQuery to totally handle the `submit` event.  A good side-effect from this is that your JavaScript and HTML will be separated and easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return currently will leave the each(), not `validateSubmit()` (validateSubmit currently doesn't return anything)

Define a variable at the begin of validateSubmit(), e.g.

```
var r=true;//default returnValue
```

and put this at the end of validateSubmit():

```
return r;
```

Now, when you want to leave validateSubmit() , call inside the each:

```
r=false;return;
```

This will leave the `each()` and also `validateSubmit()` with the returnValue `r`(what will be `false` now)

Comment: +1, nice one, I didn't even notice the `each` untill just now when working on the fiddle. For OP, it mentions this also in the [**jQuery.each() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) : `We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false.`

Comment: Thank you! That's helped a lot!

Comment: Completely fixed, Thank you very much!

Comment: @HenryPye   tried explaining this in comment yesterday about same code but you never came back with more details  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414297/jquery-checking-an-input-box-against-another-input-box-in-a-php-while-loop

Answer (score 0):

Add a [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) call to your code. Change the line:

```
function validateSubmit(){
```

to the following

```
function validateSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: That didn't work, it doesn't come up with any error messages on submit now

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your button uses 'return' also to return the returned value:

```
 <input type="submit" onClick="return validateSumbit();" />
```

Also you should remove the onsubmit handler from the form tag.

Comment: The problem is definitely within the jQuery, I just added that in and it displayed the Alert box twice but carried on submitting

Comment: To what jQuery do you refer?

Answer (score 0):

Your `validateSubmit()` function doesn't seem to return a value. Only the callback function of the `each()` method returns a value, but your actual submit handler does not. In essence, your validation code runs as expected, displaying the error messages but not returning any value to indicate of failure.

You should define a variable within the scope of `validateSubmit()` which the `each()` method can modify and return that.

For example:

```
 function validateSubmit() {
     var form_is_valid = true;

     $('tr').each( function() {
         // Validation goes here
         if (something_is_invalid) {
             form_is_valid = false;
             return;
         }
     });

     return form_is_valid;
 }
```